# Azure web app session and ARR

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, arr

I have a MVC application deployed to Azure Web app.The web app required to scale out in multiple instances.
I want to use Session object (ASP.NET) to store some user data etc.(lightweight), so that can  be retrieved quickly.I believe, session will be In-Proc with ARR ON setting.

I've the following questions

1. Is it ok to use session object in Azure web apps ,will it give
   guarantee to use same In-Proc session if ARR is on.
2. If ARR turned off ,Should I use session object?
3. Because using Session itself makes application slow,what are the
       other alternatives to store small data within Azure webapp/MVC(once authenticated user profile
           related  data) for quick access in application?

Answer (score 3):

Using **IN-PROC** sessions in the cloud is a strict no. The reason to host to cloud is to have **high availability** which is done by having a **distributed environment**.

To answer your question, the **ARR-Affinity** cookie will affinitize the client requests to a specific instance. However, if the `Process restarts` or `App-Domain` recycles, then all the sessions will be lost. This is one of the primary reasons why **Out-Proc** session state management is suggested.

I would recommend against using In-Proc session state in any cloud scenario. I understand speed is a concern for you. For this consider using **Redis Cache**. Refer the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider

HTH

Comment: Thanks Kaushal,Can't go for Redis cache due to cost limitation.Considering sql or table storage

Comment: That's a bad bad idea. If you're reading/writing session data often, latency will bring the app to its knees. You can't really replace in-memory store with durable store and get away with it. Also the tiniest Redis standard instance (don't go with Basic, that's master only not master/slave) isn't that expensive, and it's more than enough capacity for session store.